# How can i do the user redirect automatically to oauth dialog when enter to canvas url?

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, authentication

Regards,

Back, when "Authenticated Referrals" not depreciated, if the user entered to my facebook application through the canvas url, was redirected to dialogue authorization (for permissions).

Now that do not exist the option, I must do it manually so you can redirect url through the canvas.

I am using Codeigniter for it and from what I see, facebook cancel any redirection I do.

Here is my code:

```
try {
            $fb_id = $this->facebook->getUser();
            if ($fb_id) {
                $fb_data = $this->facebook->api('/me');
                return $fb_data;
            } else {
                echo 'You don't give me the permissions';
                $url = $url = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
                    'scope' => 'email,user_likes,user_about_me,publish_stream,user_birthday',
                    'redirect_uri' => $this->config->item('app_name')
                        ));
                header("location:$url");
                redirect($url, 'refresh');
            }
        } catch (Exception $exc) {
            echo $exc;
        }
```

Is there a simpler way to do it? Any examples you can show me? Thanks in advance

NOTE: My application is a (for now) recorder audio for users
First is a registration with personal information.
Then show the recorder audio.

My target is when a new user find my application (apps.facebook.com/my_app), enter to my app and show automatically the oauth dialog for permission (as before). Then enter to the registration view.

Comment: What actually you are trying to Achive , what is the functionality of your application , Could you please elaborate a bit , So that we can help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with codeigniter, just make sure that your `redirect_uri` is your canvas page URL "`apps.facebook.com/app_name`".

And then use Javascript to redirect the user to the OAuth dialog with something like:

```
echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $url . "'</script>");
```

also check out the [Canvas Tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/).

Comment: if i want redirect to my landing page, after user give me the permission? My redirect_uri is the url of the landing page?
If i put this, always give a error.

Comment: What error? try searching it here on Stackoverflow and hopefully you would find an answer.